# Javascript will not load the pictures

Tags: javascript

I want to load these banner.png files to the screen but all it prints out is the actual text from the banner array?

```
function randImg(){
var banner = new Array();

banner[0] = 'banner1.png';
banner[1] = 'banner2.png';
banner[2] = 'banner3.png';
maxImg = banner.length;
randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*maxImg);
return banner[randNum];
}
```

any thoughts? I think I need to some how add a src but I am not sure how.

Comment: Where did you call in your html this function?

Comment: in a <p> tag inside a div on my page

Comment: Post the HTML to which this applies, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be too obvious, but...

```
function randImg(){
    var banner = new Array();

    banner[0] = 'banner1.png';
    banner[1] = 'banner2.png';
    banner[2] = 'banner3.png';
    maxImg = banner.length;
    randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*maxImg);
    return '<img src="' + banner[randNum] + '" />';
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/u7yfq/

Comment: Why was my comment removed? -1 This function might work but it encourages the user to follow a bad practice and write code that will eventually be difficult to maintain.

Comment: @Ale Please tell me what is wrong with it instead of just telling me its bad.

Answer (score 1):

My pure javascript DOM manipulation is a little fuzzy (usually use jquery) but something like this should do the trick:

```
<div id="images"></div>    

<script type="text/javascript">
function randImg(){
       var banner = new Array();

       banner[0] = 'banner1.png';
       banner[1] = 'banner2.png';
       banner[2] = 'banner3.png';
       maxImg = banner.length;
       randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*maxImg);

       var container = document.getElementById('images');

       var img = document.createElement('img');
       img.setAttribute('src',banner[randNum]);

       container.appendChild(img);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: correct me if I am wrong (I am new) but are you not supposed to use "var" to declare a variable after the first lines of the function?

Comment: Using the keyword `var` will declare the variable in that scope. JavaScript uses lexical scoping. So wherever you use `var` will basically treat that scope as the new parent scope for that variable name. It's a good practice to use `var` inside your functions so you don't accidentally run into naming conflicts and/or clutter the global scope. When you omit the keyword `var` when declaring the variable inside the function, you assume that variable has been declared as global - and if it hasn't, you can run into some funky variable hoisting and closure behaviors you weren't anticipating.

Comment: So better practice would be to use 'var' before you declare all variables in a function, if they are not already declared global?

Comment: Correct. And you can declare them all at once with commas: `var foo = 1, bar = 2, baz = 3, bat = true;`

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to explain this to me.

Answer (score 0):

The instruction that loads the image should be like this.

Where imgElement is an IMG element.

```
imgElement.src = randImg();
```

If you don’t know how to get an IMG element. Give the IMG element an ID attribute and load this like this.

For an IMG element as `<img id="myImage" src="" />`
Then:

```
var imgElement = document.getElementById("myImage");
imgElement.src = randImg();
```

**Note**.- my answer gives instruction on how to change the source of an IMG element that exists in the DOM (It is recommended to do so). You should NEVER `document.write()` an element, Neither on demand or when page is loading. That practice has been deprecated and many browsers would delete the whole page contents if you do so.

Comment: +1 This answer should have been accepted, the simplest solution and very well designed.

Comment: @Mario there is no need to be rude I am trying to teach myself a new language. The answer that I selected worked it was not because I was being malicious towards you. It was the first one that I came across that I could get to work. If you are here to help explain why in detail what I am doing wrong and how your code works and us newbies can have the opportunity to grasp the material. That is why I am here in the first place.

Comment: @EdwardNickAJubrey I was referring to them since you disappeared yesterday. My point is that using such a method for that results in a practice that will lead to maintainability issues for bigger projects. So it is better to always avoid it. (including HTML in Javascript code, this is why I did not do it in my answer and expected my point to be understood) I gave good explanations yesterday but they were all deleted for some reason. They did not want to understand and they prefer to stick to this kind of quick but dirty ways to work with Javascript.